# Compiling with -Xlint getting unchecked call to add(E)

Tags: java, generics, queue

EDIT: This is just a tiny snippet of the code if you have any questions I can post more.

Trying to write a process scheduling algorithm in Java using Queues and I am running into this warning. Can anyone help me fix this warning?

```
prog2.java:115: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.Collection
                    notSubmitted.add(p[r]);
```

Here is the code that I am having trouble with. I think I need to use Generics but I haven't used them before.

```
static Queue notSubmitted = new LinkedList();
...
for(int j = 0; j < numProcesses; ++j)
            {
                    pid = i.nextInt();
                    priority = i.nextInt();
                    submissionTime = i.nextInt();
                    totalCpuTime = i.nextInt();
                    computeTime = i.nextInt();
                    ioTime = i.nextInt();
                    p[j] = new Process(pid, priority, submissionTime, totalCpuTime, computeTime, ioTime);
            }
for(int r = 0; r < numProcesses; ++r)
            {
                    //populate the not submitted queue first
                    notSubmitted.add(p[r]);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the warning, you can use generics in your queue declaration as follows (Java 5 & 6):

```
static Queue<Process> notSubmitted = new LinkedList<Process>();
```

or if you use Java 7+:

```
static Queue<Process> notSubmitted = new LinkedList<>();
```

That tells the compiler that you only plan to add `Process` objects to that list.

Answer (score 2):

If your `p[]` is of type `Process[]`, then you simply use the following declaration for your queue:

```
static Queue<Process> notSubmitted = new LinkedList<Process>();
```

Which indicates that the queue contains object of the type `Process` (it can also contain subclasses of the type `Process`).

Answer (score 1):

Add generic to your Queue:

`static Queue<Process> notSubmitted = new LinkedList<Process>();`